# How can i add tag in XML file using python

Tags: python, xml

i have the following XML file :

```
<user-response date="2023-09-27T12:07:10+02:00">
  <users>
    <user>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name1</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 1</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
    <user>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name 2</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 2</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
  </users>
</user-response>
```

i want to add a specific tag after `<user>` and before `<user-data>`

i tried the following code :

```
def modify_xml(file_name_result,file_location,file_destination):

    with open(file_location, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        tree = ET.parse(f)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for elem in root.iter():
            if elem.tag == 'user':
                ET.SubElement(elem,'validation-test')

    tree.write(file_destination, encoding='utf-8')
```

i also tried :

```
    xml_text = ET.XML('''<validation-test/>''')
    for elem in tree.findall('./users/user'):
        elem.append(xml_text)
```

No error so far but the tag is added at the end giving the following result :

```
<user-response date="2023-09-27T12:07:10+02:00">
  <users>
    <user>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name1</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 1</first-name>
      </user-data>
    <validation-test /></user>
    <user>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name 2</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 2</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
  <validation-test /></users>
</user-response>
```

i don't understand what i'm doing wrong, can someone help me please? i hope that i was clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks. And call XSLT from Python.

Comment: No it's not. Using ElementTree is a perfectly fine and regularly utilized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `SubElement` doesn't work because `SubElement` appends an element *after* the named element:

> Subelement factory. This function creates an element instance, and appends it to an existing element

You want to add a new child element, which you can do using the `.insert` method:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def modify_xml(input_file, output_file):

    with open(input_file, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        tree = ET.parse(f)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for elem in root.iter():
            if elem.tag == 'user':
                elem.insert(0, ET.Element('validation-test'))

    tree.write(output_file, encoding='utf-8')


modify_xml('data.xml', 'data_patched.xml')
```

Given your sample input, that produces:

```
<user-response date="2023-09-27T12:07:10+02:00">
  <users>
    <user>
      <validation-test/><user-data>
        <last-name>last name1</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 1</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
    <user>
      <validation-test/><user-data>
        <last-name>last name 2</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 2</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
  </users>
</user-response>
```

---

> Thank you for your answer @larsks, what if i want  to be at the same level as  not inside? like :
>
> ```
> <user>
>   <validation-test />
>   <user-data>...</user-data>
> </user>
> ```

That is exactly what I show in the above answer. There's no difference between this snippet and my original answer: the `<validation-test>` element is contained inside the `<user>` element.

Comment: Please see my update to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT implementation for comparison.

A tiny XSLT template does the job:

```
<xsl:template match="user-data">
    <validation-test/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Input XML**

```
<user-response date="2023-09-27T12:07:10+02:00">
    <users>
        <user>
            <user-data>
                <last-name>last name1</last-name>
                <first-name>first name 1</first-name>
            </user-data>
        </user>
        <user>
            <user-data>
                <last-name>last name 2</last-name>
                <first-name>first name 2</first-name>
            </user-data>
        </user>
    </users>
</user-response>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
                omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="user-data">
        <validation-test/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<user-response date="2023-09-27T12:07:10+02:00">
  <users>
    <user>
      <validation-test/>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name1</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 1</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
    <user>
      <validation-test/>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name 2</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 2</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
  </users>
</user-response>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("Input.xml")
style = lx.parse("Style.xslt")
outfile = "output.xml"

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open(outfile, "wb") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a list comprehensive:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<user-response date="2023-09-27T12:07:10+02:00">
  <users>
    <user>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name1</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 1</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
    <user>
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name 2</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 2</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
  </users>
</user-response>"""


root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

# Insert element on index 0
[elem.insert(0, ET.Element('validation-test')) for elem in root.findall('.//user')]

# Nice print           
ET.indent(root, space="  ")
ET.dump(root)

# If a file is needed
#tree.write("new.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

```
<user-response date="2023-09-27T12:07:10+02:00">
  <users>
    <user>
      <validation-test />
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name1</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 1</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
    <user>
      <validation-test />
      <user-data>
        <last-name>last name 2</last-name>
        <first-name>first name 2</first-name>
      </user-data>
    </user>
  </users>
</user-response>
```